# How to use Maybe base correctly?

Tags: haskell

I write a code to convert a string to be a list of Intger:

```
convert::String -> Maybe [Int]
convert (c:cs) 
    isDigit c            = Just(c: (convert cs):[])
    otherwise            = Nothing
```

and it shows an error...

```
test.hs:15:26: error:
parse error on input ‘=’
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

Why is that so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of looking at [V. Semeria's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39167144/1126841) is to use `sequence` (from the `Traversable` type class) with `map`:

```
import Data.Char -- for ord

convertChar :: Char -> Maybe Int
convertChar c = if isDigit c then Just $ ord c - 48 else Nothing

convert :: String -> Maybe [Int]
-- Start with String -> [Maybe Int], then convert
-- the [Maybe Int] to Maybe [Int]
convert = sequence . map convertChar
```

This is a common pattern, so `Traversable` also provides `traverse`, which in this case is equivalent to `sequence . map`.

```
convert :: Traversable t => t Char -> Maybe (t Int)
convert = traverse converChar
```

Some examples (most of the instances of `Traversable` available by default aren't very interesting, but various tree types can have instances).

```
> convert "123"
Just [1,2,3]
> convert (Just '1')
Just (Just 1)
> convert (True, '2')
Just (True, 2)
> convert (Right '1')
Just (Right 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could you please tell me why the code shows such output? I don't understand the second line of the code.

Comment: Which line, `sequence . map convertChar`?

Comment: convertChar c = if isDigit c then Just $ ord c else Nothing

Comment: I want to get [1,2,3] for input "123", and "Nothing" for a input with letter. I don't know why this line can draw an output with 49...

Comment: Ah, `ord` converts a character to its ASCII value. If you just want to "drop the quotes", so to speak, you need to subtract 48 from the result. You can't simply cast a character value to a number in Haskell.

Comment: Thank you...One last question, what is the meaning of '$'? I searched that it means grouping expression, but I don't understand clearly...

Comment: It's a low-precedence operator for function application, used to save parentheses: `Just $ ord c - 48` is equivalent to `Just (ord c - 48)`. Whereas ordinary function application has higher precedence than any infix operator (hence, no need to write `(ord c) - 48` to avoid ambiguity with `ord (c - 48)`), the `$` operator has *lower* precedence than any other infix operator.

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

While there are other compile errors in your code, the reason you're getting the error message about the parse error is because you are not including the pipe character used in guards.

```haskell
convert (c:cs) 
    | isDigit c            = Just(c: (convert cs):[])
    | otherwise            = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

There were several errors in your code. You need to try to convert each character, which gives a `Maybe Int`. Then you loop on the string using `mapM` inside the `Maybe` monad :

```
import Data.Char

convertChar :: Char -> Maybe Int
convertChar c = if isDigit c then Just $ ord c else Nothing

convert :: String -> Maybe [Int]
convert = mapM convertChar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.